# Is $(p \oplus q) \vee (q \oplus r) \vee (r \oplus p)$ satisfiable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Is $(p \oplus q) \vee (q \oplus r) \vee (r \oplus p)$ satisfiable?
($\oplus \equiv \operatorname{XOR}$)

How do I prove whether it's satisfiable or not? Some examples would help!

Answer (score 1):

The [truth table from Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table%20%5B%20(A%20XOR%20B)%20OR%20(B%20XOR%20C)%20OR%20(C%20XOR%20A)%20%5D) shows that is only false when $p=q=r$.

As it can attain a true value, it is [satisfiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability).